# mediapipe==0.10.9 How to call GPU acceleration？

Tags: python

Mediapipe=0.10.9 How to call GPU acceleration? I have configured tensorflow=2.10.0 to correctly locate CUDA on the Python side, but running the code has a CUDA utilization rate of 0.

I tried Torch and was able to find CUDA correctly, but the utilization rate of CUDA was also 0

Looking forward to accelerating the operation of Mediapipe on GPU.

Comment: Check if GPU is available as MediaPipe should automatically use the GPU if it is available and properly configured.
`print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))`

Comment: if tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU"):
        print("On GPU:")
        with tf.device("GPU:0"):
            base_options = python.BaseOptions(model_asset_path=model)
            base_options.use_gpu = True
          options = vision.PoseLandmarkerOptions(
                base_options=base_options,
                running_mode=vision.RunningMode.LIVE_STREAM,
                num_poses=num_poses,

The above code is where I called CUDA. The type you mentioned can print out my unique GPU, but during execution, the GPU utilization is only below 10%, and the CUDA utilization is only 0%